# How to be patient

Tags: workout

this question is little mind issue.I have tournaments,especially football.I am new coach i have fear inside me and I make thoughts.I am leading my players how would they play and that is my fault from my fear i talk talk talk I want to do action.I have no patient.What I want to tell is my physical health is influenced by my mind self and the whole strategy goes down.Now what has to do with the section,I believe we all struggling with be patient it is one of the biggeSt part  I think. How can I obtain endurance, strength be patient. I have read Internet but nothing related to this.I want not to react.It's difficult.I can be thinking in night too.If that text seems weird,I would do it simple how to increase my endurance -patient to something? Your opinion is respectful

Comment: Not really sure if this is directly related to fitness.

Comment: For example ,delete this scenario from your mind because confuse.I do joking and I am doing 40 km. When I have done 35 my mind start thinking when I will arrive.In a few words, I start lose my patient. In everything, physical activity there is this issue.How to forget it to "win" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been obsessively into self improvement / mastery for as long as I can remember.

---

One of the most Inspirational / unbelievable stories and life stories I've heard is from:

> Navy Seal, USAF (Tactical Air Control Party)   - **David Goggins**:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcxA-inpXqc
*(Explicit)* 
Be Uncomfortable Every Day of Your Life

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyJ_hhninDw 
    Strengthen Your Mind Like A Navy Seal

Another Great One *(by Les Miles)*: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrbsrtB_AJQ 
  Les Brown: Les Brown: Never Doubt Yourself

---

**That is one video of many - here's my most recent personal collection of over 100:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_J_bOqPhuZA 
    How to Conquer Your Mind and Embrace The Suck | David Goggins

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIrT1eHs1b0 
    The Most Motivational Talk Ever! - David Goggins | Driven   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78I9dTB9vqM 
    How to Make Yourself Immune to Pain | David Goggins on Impact Theory    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhTBeUk4_4w 
    Living with a Seal. "The real back story" - Part 1  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kHx2DpROS3g 
    Living with a Seal. "The real back story" - Part 2  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFRNHb_Z2kc 
    Living with a Seal. "The real back story" - Part 3  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VRLNgcroA7w 
    Living with a Seal. "The real back story" - Part 4  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62ockOFiy_Y 
    How to Conquer Your Mind and Embrace The Suck | David Goggins   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fzb6ST_OJus 
    Interview with Retired Navy

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uD-bYZVcqvw 
    Best Of Eric Thomas - Best Motivational Speech Videos Ever #1   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWYYELi61GU 
    Best Of Eric Thomas #3 - Best Motivational Speech Videos Ever #5    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DF9VYfiT-lg 
    Eric Thomas & Les Brown | I'AM A WINNER (Motivational Speech)   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qz11Jh4kdjI 
    Eric Thomas & Les Brown | NO EXCUSES (Motivational Speech)  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZHEbPYGM74 
    Eric Thomas ft Les Brown : HOW BAD DO YOU WANT IT | Best Motivational Speech    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AvwPrcA2hTk 
    Eric Thomas ft Les Brown: GET UP AND HIT BACK | Les Brown Motivation    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5NVlmAakFs 
    Eric Thomas, Les Brown & Billy Alsbrooks | I'M A CHAMPION (Motivational Speech) 
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9AEigQYfhJw 
    Eric Thomas's Top 10 Rules For Success  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_R8gBnhyMSA 
    Outworked Ft. Eric Thomas   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83AB3p3WXBc 
    I Am A Warrior - Eric Thomas    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKKbOkLUcq4 
    Eric Thomas's Top 10 Rules For Success - Volume 2   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsItH9Spw7o 
    Eric Thomas (ET) - LIVE YOUR DREAMS 
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozhcHDjaqN0 
    Les Brown  Never Complain Ever Again  BEST MOTIVATIONAL VIDEO   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1F94TBpUOk 
    Les Brown: Make Yourself Unbeatable | Les Brown Motivation  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-bJmRoPb7uM 
    Les Brown: Never Doubt Yourself | Les Brown Motivation  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wutwhc9gdIA 
    Les Brown: Psychology Of The Great | Les Brown Motivation   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaqz7dJpyEk 
    Les Brown: Take Back Control Of Your Life | Les Brown Motivation    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsD9Nt9U_3U 
    Les Brown: The Lion Attitude | Les Brown Motivation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LgS_5bSXmiI 
    Act Like A Success | Motivational Video For Success & Studying (Destroy Bad Habits) 
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjjYVROiJIA 
    Be Fearless (Greatest Motivational Ever!)   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzhzkKccBi8 
    Be Phenomenal   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0FFNcIYZMI 
    Be Powerful - Motivational Speech   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjZ0KbJcav0 
    Believe In Yourself | Motivational Video    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmAFMNmSKus 
    Best Motivational Video | Speeches Compilation 1 Hour Long  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=As8XkJNaHbs 
    Best Speech Ever - Simon Sinek On Millennials In The Workplace | So Inspiring!  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZB3SLa1A7x8 
    Change Your Mentality | New Motivational Compilation 2017   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8EGWEUf9Xr8 
    Dear Hard Work  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrUpjCK3kpQ 
    Destroy Doubt | Motivational Speech For Success 2017    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOdfsOA1yLA 
    Discipline Is Everything - New Motivational Video Compilation   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYMUb4uQZoo 
    Do What Is Hard 
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQI_XBmlQLU 
    Don't Waste Time - One Of The Greatest Motivational Speech Videos Of 2017 - Td Jakes Motivation 
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67fB-mqtXbY 
    Effort  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjwPgmPxGwQ 
    End Laziness  -  Inspirational Running Video - (Very Powerful Motivation)   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdfzEU5xY2M 
    Enraged 
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2gyQ52jv3g 
    Fear Failure And Success    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8o1cQqoiBa8 
    Get Back Up 
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3WrCx3mwNo 
    Get Up & Get It Done | New Motivational Video Compilation For Success & Studying    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kirDKmZhOd8 
    Hold The Line | Be Disciplined / End Laziness | Morning Motivation | Best Motivational Video    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsSC2vx7zFQ 
    How Bad Do You Want It  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6xLYt265ZM 
    How Great Am I  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twD9MGJ3R7c 
    JOE ROGAN - Motivational Video [BE A HERO]  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2B4_HtZkRVY 
    Listen To This When You Wake Up | Morning Motivation | Best Motivational Video Ever 
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FhzNSPiqO0M 
    Lost But Won    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWlXsEj1RpM 
    Motivation - Become A Lion  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzbCLooj-M8 
    Never Quit  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urzSKs-TmBc 
    No Fear 
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7pTeEazrWU 
    No Longer A Loser (Ray Lewis) Motivation For Life   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9fXOivDGU8 
    NO MATTER HOW HARD IT GETS - Motivational video 
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBN5nZc65YU 
    Nothing Will Stop Me    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BW3EA0AdZx0 
    Obsessed With Success   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pnECGf4WsiU 
    Outcast Motivational Video  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9G3e06N4qSs 
    Pain Is Temporary   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nb6iN6nGSgo 
    Potential   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e10nwjIeZoE 
    Prove Them All Wrong - The Most Inspiring Speeches From Successful People Who Believed In Themselves    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPQ1budJRIQ 
    Prove Them Wrong    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSosye3xQiE 
    PURSUIT OF THE IMPOSSIBLE - Motivational Video  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OAhdERIyi8Y 
    RISE UP - Best MOTIVATIONAL VIDEO Compilation of All Time   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UX2tefQHNmk 
    Stop Killing Time   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-pC3AjI9DI 
    Take Action 
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYKsbld6LII 
    The Most Motivating 8 Min Of Your Life  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ltDn2xqJPY 
    The Video That Will Change Your Future - One Of The Best Motivational Videos Ever   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HeGPn5zxegY 
    The Winning Mentality | Powerful Motivation 2017    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aDCGrINPGUQ 
    Through Hell    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMnHeLxoWAY 
    Today I Will Do What Others Won't! | Best Motivational Speech Compilation Ever  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9PXj4Rj94Q 
    Top 10 - Most Epic Motivational Speeches Ever (All Time)    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Thnbf7al1TI 
    Ultimate 25min+ Inspirational Motivational Video    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DX8ZeA7ahDg 
    Unexpected | Ray Lewis  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9z4Kft47kBM 
    Unstoppable 
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbAQemOMi1k 
    Wake Up & Work Hard At It | Motivational Video Compilation For Success & Studying   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7RwzSuvTgs 
    Watch This When You Feel Lazy - Workout Motivation Video 2017   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRaTpTVTENU 
    What Do You Want To Be Remembered For?  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkCFHKFCYGA 
    What's Your Why 
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXJ1FZKwI7c 
    You Are Limitless   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4EiM_-oSWzI 
    You Will Win    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVG4wgCqeEQ 
    The Mindset Of High Achievers - Best Motivational Video For Success In Life & Study 2017    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwCkU3h_yWc 
    Endure The Pain - Best Gym Motivation Video 2017 - Motivational Workout Speeches    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Pq2j_ji-XE 
    When You Are About To Give Up | New Motivational Video (Very Powerful)

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCR54lF_dD3f-8srmRqnTwgQ/playlists  
    Motivationhub By Motiversity Playlists  
    
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnHM4JExdHkswGVTYecSaCyDfK3z6A9AN    
    David Goggins - The Hardest Man Alive Motivation    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0kidOBV7yxY 
    Goggins Iron Man    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtDc_iJ-j-M 
    How to Wake Up Early - And Not be Miserable 
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9I_u4oZqF8c 
    Navy SEAL Has a '40 Percent Rule' And It's the Key to Overcoming Mental Barriers    
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qt5pkTlWBY 
    One of the Most Motivational Videos You'll Ever See | SELF DISCIPLINE   
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8QY0NDWqzk 
    The Most Successful People Explain Why a College Degree is USELESS  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fSLbC-1b0Q 
    When You Are About To Give Up - Motivational Video Speeches Compilation 1 HOUR  
    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_mzgBoAur8 
    Your Only Limit Is You - Epic Motivational Video

Comment: The lion attitude doesn't exist this video

Comment: No problem, hope it helps you.   I understand it's somewhat off topic so I think it's gonna be closed soon.  If not I have fixes for those links if anyone wants tons of others I can post